# CRF++-058 on MAC

Tags: macos, unix, machine-learning, crf, crf++

I barely new on using mac and I got some problems when I tried running a tool from a command-line. I am trying to run a software that required a CRF++. Here is the errors;

```
Cannot load the example native code.
Make sure your LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains '.'
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no CRFPP in java.library.path
```

I have installed the CRF++-058 on my machine. I used brew to install the CRF++ 0.58.

```
  /usr/local/Cellar/crf++/0.58: 11 files, 784K, built in 32 seconds
```

here is the output of the brew doctor

```
Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libcrfpp.la
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As with any `homebrew` problems, try:

```
brew doctor
```

first and follow the good doctor's advice.

Failing that, try

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and see if it contains the dot that it wants. If not, try editing $HOME/.profile and add a line like

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.
```

then logout and login again and try running your program.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited my question so you can see the output of the brew doctor. Honestly, since I am barely new on using this machine, i am afraid I could not really understand how to edit $HOME/.profile. by the way, when I echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I got nothing (empty perhaps). @Mark Setchell

Comment: I deleted the .la on my /usr/local/lib, then when I ran the brew doctor, it says that my system is ready to brew

Comment: Try just typing `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` and then running your program. If that works, we can work on setting it permanently by starting 'Textedit` and editing `.profile` in your Home directory.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I just did both. First, I tried to use export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. and ran my program. Yet, it did not work. Then I tried to create the ~/.bash_profile, and add export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. Yet, it did not work either :(

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when using crfpp with java.

my original code like this.

```
static {
    try {
        sf_model="/~/java";
        sf_tagger = new Tagger(String.format("-m %s -v 3 -n2", sf_model+"/crfmodel"));
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot load the example native code.\nMake sure your LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains \'.\'\n" + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

but I added one line and the problem solved

```
static {
    try {
        sf_model="/~/java";
        System.load(sf_model + "/libCRFPP.so");
        sf_tagger = new Tagger(String.format("-m %s -v 3 -n2", sf_model+"/crfmodel"));
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot load the example native code.\nMake sure your LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains \'.\'\n" + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```